# Authenticate a user by role

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a user with ROLE_ADMIN and I want to connect him as "ROLE_USER" when calling http://localhost/login but connect him as "ROLE_ADMIN" when calling http://localhost/login?role=admin.
Is it possible to do it in Symfony ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if the "role" GET parameter is set and defined as "admin" and then write your code.

If there is a role inheritance and that your admin has ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN, just define custom actions if you detect that it's an admin:

```
        if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            //adminCode
        } else {
           //userCode
        }
```